# Do I need a comma in the end of the first part of a sentence that mentions an object of a verb that will be mentioned in the verb of the second part?

Tags: punctuation

Do I need a comma in the end of the first part of a sentence that mentions an object of a verb that will be mentioned in the verb of the second part?

For example:

> Whatever **desires** she may have, our company will be more than happy
>   to **meet** them.

Object:  desires;
Verb: meet;

Another example:

> Abby is a very funny and hilarious girl. Whatever **lacks** she may
>   have in terms of English, she successfully **makes up for** them by
>   her sense of humor and ability to play her parts well in skits.

Object:  lacks;
Verb: make up for;

So, are commas in those sentences necessary?

Comment: @BillJ: I disagree. To ***my*** ear, OP's second example is ungrammatical because of the pronoun ***them***, which in your rewrite is replaced by ***it***. I think the plurality of the thing/things lacking is irrelevant - the point is that in ***my*** version of "grammatically valid", there should be no pronoun there in the first place. It's like *Whatever you want I will give you* (as opposed to *Whatever you want I will give **it** to you*).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - “To my ear, OP's second example is ungrammatical because of the pronoun them”
- I don’t understand why it is ungrammatical. The noun “lacks” is plural, so the pronoun “them”, which is the anaphor of “lacks”, is also plural. “…there should be no pronoun there in the first place” – So, can I put it in this way then: “Whatever lacks she may have in terms of English, she successfully makes up for by her sense of humor…”?

Comment: The reason I find those "extraneous" pronouns "ungrammatical" (or at least, "unidiomatic") is because starting from ***I have what[ever] you need*** the stylistic inversion gives me ***What[ever] you need I have***, with no place for a pronoun (and obviously I couldn't have started with *I have what you need **it***).

Comment: @brilliant You can't possess "lacks". In any case, "lack" is a non-count noun. You're misusing the word. "Lack" is used in constructions like "The case was dismissed for lack of evidence".

Comment: @BillJ - “Love at twelve years of age had had many lacks of life…” (“The Love of Parson Lord” by Mary Eleanor Wilkins). Link: https://www.amazon.com/Love-Parson-Lord-Stories-Classic/dp/0483999954

Comment: @BillJ: There are plenty of written instances of [***lack are***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lacks+are%22) I don't see a big problem with pluralising the word.

Comment: @brilliant That's not a standard use, though it occurs in literary use.

Comment: @brilliant: But idiomatically, just about any native speaker today would choose ***deficiencies*** or similar, rather than ***lacks***.

Comment: @BillJ - I understand now that it's better not to use the noun "lacks", but I still don't understand whether or not I can drop "them" at all (in other words, whether or not I can say: “Whatever deficiencies she may have in terms of English, she successfully makes up for by her sense of humor…”), and I still don't have an answer to my main question about comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about punctuation are not questions about grammar. They ultimately are determined by styleguides, which vary. Nevertheless, most styleguides assume certain conventions of punctuation: a comma generally marks the termination of a subordinate clause placed at the beginning of a sentence. Note that this word order is relatively infrequent in everyday speech, where the usual sequence is to start with the independent clause. When the subordinate clause does precede the main clause in speech, the speaker almost invariably pauses briefly between the subordinate and independent clauses. Use of commas in written English frequently mirrors the use of brief pauses in spoken English.

So your examples represent restrictive relative clauses placed before the independent clause and so would, in most styleguides, require termination with a comma, but not because of some rule relating two verbs having the same object. (In fact, I suspect that most grammarians would say that the relative clause as a whole is the object of one verb, but I dislike terminological disputes.)

> Whatever desires she may have, our company will meet
>
> Our company will meet whatever desires she may have

(I cannot **quite** agree with FumbleFingers that the redundant "them" in your first example is blatantly ungrammatical because the "them" in the second example is clearly necessary, but the use of "them" in the first example does strike me as odd.)

> Whatever deficiencies in English she may have, she successfully makes up for them through her ...
>
> She successfully makes up for whatever deficiencies she may have in English through her ...

(I cannot agree with BillJ's **apparent** implication that "lack" can never be used as an object. "He showed a great lack of tact when talking to the judge." But I do agree that "lack" as a noun is almost never treated as a count noun and that "lacks" in your example is not idiomatic in modern English.)

In short, relative clauses placed at the beginning of a sentence should be terminated by a comma. Stylistically, they strike me as stretching normal word order a bit far, and I would use them rarely.